# Submitting a plugin form to database in admin page

Tags: plugin-development, forms

I have an admin page in my plugin that contains a form which is to submit to a custom table created during plugin activation. Here is how I went about it:

The following php and html codes are placed on that plugin page.

```
<?php
//php code to receive form data and submit to table goes here
?>

<form method="post" action="">
.....
</form>
```

It works, but what is a better method of doing this, especially with Ajax.

Comment: Use [Settings API](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/settings/settings-api/) to build the form and manage it, use [Ajax API](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) to send the form by Ajax request.

Answer (score -1):

**[UPDATE]**
You should have the page divided in two section-
1. One dealing with AJAX request and Post Method
2. Displaying form data

Here is outline

```
<?php


if (strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest'  or $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
// Process AJAX Request or POST Method
}
if (strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) != 'xmlhttprequest'){
// HTML Code here which will not be returned to AJAX Call
}
?>
```

As html code will be returned with ajax response that will cause trouble if not filtered.